# Verification of proof that $x^p+y^p<(x+y)^p$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I came across the inequality $x^p+y^p<(x+y)^p$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $p>1$ during working on an assignment.  While I think I have a proof down, I'm not 100% confident about the steps taken.

My proof is simple enough: fix $y>0$ and define the function $f(x)=(x+y)^p-x^p-y^p$.  Differentiating on the interval $(0,\infty)$, we get $f'=p(x+y)^{p-1}-px^{p-1}$ which is clearly positive on this interval given our restraints on $x, y$, and $p$. Thus, $f$ is increasing on this interval.  Hence, $f(x)>f(0)=0$ for all $x>0$ and arbitrary $y>0$ and this inequality is proved.

My question is a brief one: does the step of fixing $y>0$ affect the proof? Since $y$ is arbitrary, I don't really see any problem (at least, on the surface) that would arise, but I'm not quite convinced yet.

Comment: Your proof is fine. But, I have an alternative way. See my answer below:

Comment: It's no problem. Fixing an _arbitrary_ $y$ (or whatever the variable/parameter is called) is a common way to prove something for _all_ values of the variable/parameter. An alternative proof is to divide by $(x+y)^p$, and $$\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)^p + \left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)^p < \frac{x}{x+y} + \frac{y}{x+y}$$ follows since $0 < \frac{x}{x+y},\frac{y}{x+y} < 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Jlamprong - Thanks, I thought that would be the case. I couldn't get rid of the small nagging doubt I had, so I thought I'd ask to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $p>1$ and $x,y>0$ then $$\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)^p<\frac{x}{x+y}\textrm{and }\left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)^p<\frac{y}{x+y}.$$ It follows that $$\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)^p+\left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)^p<\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{x+y}=1$$ that leads to what you wanted.

Comment: Oi! I hadn't seen this proof before. Nice.